# ajax pagination issue with history.back()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pagination

==> load page N ==>  click a list ==> list detail page. 
Then when I do "previous button" from browser, I landed in page 1, not page N.

I just realized ajax pagination has this issue.

As of now, I only can think of a workaround solution, which is :
- after clicking the list, open a new tab instead using the original tab. 
  At least user don't struggle to find the previous page N.

Is there any other solution ? 
To be specific, 
How to land in page N after clicking previous button from browser (with ajax pagination)?

Comment: Use the History API (which isn't supported in all browsers) or use a hack involving a hidden iframe to make the Back button work.

Answer (score 2):

You can [modify the browser's history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) by using

history.pushState() or history.replaceState()

So, when you load page N, you run this (as per the Mozilla developer's page)

var stateObj = { foo: "bar" }; //save your data here if your URL is not descriptive enough

history.pushState(stateObj, "pageTitle", "pathName");

If you are using the stateObj you need to listen for the 'popstate' event to retrieve your data and restore the appropriate state.

This is part of the HTML5 spec, so it might not work in older browsers.